# 'id' is already declared in the upper scope

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to map over the object and I'm getting eslint error `'id' is already declared in the upper scope`

```
data.map(({ id, profileName, name }) => ({
      id,
      name: `${profileName} - ${name}`
    }))
```

I tried to change the id to dataId but then I'm getting id as undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you have id in the upperscope, to change `id` to something else you can do this:

```js
data.map(({ id: somethingElse, profileName, name }) => ({
      id: somethingElse,
      name: `${profileName} - ${name}`
}))
```

Comment: oh, ok thank you! I forgot to use the same id when I returned the ID.